# formatting comma separated parameter in vs2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i have a code like this

```
void method1(param1
             ,param2
             ,param3){...}
```

but when i press ctrl+k , ctrl+d to reformat the class, it will be formatted as flow

```
void method1(param1
             ,
              param2
             ,
              param3){...}
```

i know that it will be fix if i put the comma after param Name but i really want it to be before param Name. how can i inform the auto format future of vs2010 to format my method as follow:

```
void method1(param1
             ,param2
             ,param3){...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Formatting
```

if you use resharper loot at [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html#Code_Formatting)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) you can configure how you want application tidy-ups to be run (along with providing some other useful features).